# How to add rtl support to angular chosen

Tags: html, css, angularjs, jquery-chosen, angular-chosen

I'm using angular with chosen ( [source](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/222)) , and i'm trying to add rtl support , here is my Demo . i've read this but it's not working   .

The problem is when body has dir="rtl" attribute after click on select list , page get horizantal scroll .

```
 <select class="chzn-rtl" chosen disable-search="false"
  no-results-text="'Tough luck'"
  ng-model="bar">
    <option>Hi</option>
    <option>This is fun</option>
    <option>I like Chosen so much</option>
    <option>I also like bunny rabbits</option>
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/XOBiVHrHPA1Jm96mdNLE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `chosen` dropdown never getting close &
On start up it goes most left of the end where scroll bar end.

**CSS**

```
.chosen-container{
  .position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Adding inside your style will fix this problem. I haven't find any good fix for it. This is some what hacky way but this work around I found.

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bOW2KpijmIBXCF1MHEz0?p=preview)

Thanks.